# How to pass all local variables to another function?

Tags: python

I have two functions: `functionA` and `functionB` and I would like to call `functionB` inside `functionA` and pass to it all local variables defined in `functionA` (and in the other way). For example I would like to make the below code works:

```
def functionA():
    localA = 20
    functionB()
    print(localB)

def functionB():
    print(localA)
    localB=10

functionA()
```

Comment: If you want to share all locals between the functions then should it not just be a single function instead?

Comment: Just pass them as parameters to `functionB()` and return them back again.

Comment: Yes but this function is quite long and I want to split it to `functionB` where a part of calculations will be done. I will have a lot of argument in function A and I want to return also a lot of argument from function B so I would like to avoid any parameters especially to function B

Comment: Have you tried using kwargs?

Answer (score 2):

Pass the local variables of `functionA` as parameters to `functionB`. Return the local variables of `functionB` to `functionA`:

```
def functionA():
    localA = 20
    localB = functionB(localA)
    print(localB)

def functionB(localA):
    print(localA)
    localB = 10
    return localB
```

Comment: I don't want to pass arguments to `functionB` inside `functionA`.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why not?

Comment: Because I will have a lot of them. The idea is that I have a lot of calculations to do in function A and I would like to do some of them in function B to make the code better organized

Comment: Not using parameters and using some weird tricks to use the local variables in function B is probably going to be a lot less organised.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if what you want to do is the ideal solution, but perhaps you could try something like this:

```py
def functionB(local_vars):
    print(local_vars["localA"])

def functionA():
    localA = 20
    local_vars = {k: v for k, v in locals().items() if not k.startswith('_')}
    functionB(local_vars)
```

Answer (score 0):

If there's much information that the two functions need to share, I would suggest encapsulating the what they're doing in combination into a class and making all the local variables that need to shared instance attributes prefixed with `self.`.

Here's what I mean:

```
class ComboFuncs:
    def functionA(self):
        self.localA = 20
        self.functionB()
        print(self.localB)

    def functionB(self):
        print(self.localA)
        self.localB = 10


ComboFuncs().functionA()
```